# The first letter missing on input field

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using these two almost identical functions to catch a keypress event in an input field, and clear the label inside it. But for some reason the first letter I type won't appear in the password field, while it appears in the username field. What could be the cause of this?

```
$("#username").keypress(function()
{
  if($(this).hasClass("label"))
  {
    $(this).removeClass("label");
    $(this).val("");
  }
});

$("#password").keypress(function()
{
  if($(this).hasClass("label"))
  {
    $(this).removeClass("label");
    $(this).prop("type", "password");
    $(this).val("");
  }
});
```

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/c0qdj1u3/

Comment: Works fine for me Chrome ... Windows

Comment: This seems to be a browser issue.

Comment: Works fine Chrome on OS X

Comment: I'm using Firefox 47 on Linux, can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Confirmed Firefox on Windows has the issue

Comment: My question is why you just don't use the `placeholder` attr to set that instead the default values https://jsfiddle.net/c0qdj1u3/1/

Comment: @DaniP thanks for that tip, it's only for IE10+ though so I probably won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is causing the bug:

```
    $(this).prop("type", "password");
```

If you start off as the type being password, it works fine. Instead of setting the value, use a placeholder. See below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="label" id="username"><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="label" id="password">

$("#username").keypress(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass("label"))
  {
    $(this).removeClass("label");
    $(this).val("");
  }
});

$("#password").keypress(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass("label"))
  {
    $(this).removeClass("label");
    $(this).val("");
  }
});
```

If you MUST have some value in the text box prior to any typing, try using the jQuery-Placeholder plugin. https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: Yes I know that line is causing it, but why? I don't want to use placeholder because IE9 doesn't support it apparently. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: You need text to be there ahead of time?

Comment: Yes, as it's the input field label. I don't want to use any plugins for such a simple thing also.

Comment: See updated answer. Doing it this way will automatically switch between HTML5 placeholder and the jQuery-Placeholder for you.